# embed lightning component in detail record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, detail-page

how should i **embed my lightning component in detail record** page of any object.

i don't want to use quick action or any other button.

i want my lightning component should directly be **visible in fields section** of any object i.e when user opens any detail record page.

so that user can directly use my component without wasting time and navigation problem.

i don't want to use or create multiple pages for each object, and i wan't a solution that should work in both classic and lightning view.

Answer (score 1):

1.In Lightning Experiance using **APP Builder** you can do it. refer this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm&language=en_US&type=0) for more details

2.In Salesforce classic you may use **Lightning out**  i.e Embedd Lightning component in visual force page  refer this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) for more detail.Then embedd **VF** page in page Layout

Comment: i don't want to use or create multiple pages for each object, and i wan't a solution that should work in both classic and lightning view.

Comment: Embedd component in VF page.Is the only way to use lightning component   in salesforce classic.