# Can the Lightning Page created through the App Builder be surfaced in Lightning Out?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Can the Lightning Page created through the App Builder be surfaced in Lightning Out?

It appears that only stand alone Apps can be surfaced in lightning out.

Answer (score 1):

Nope . For **lightning out** You can Embedd Lightning component in visual force page.To add vfpage in sales force classic . Refer this [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/161636/38798) for more details